# How to remove currency symbol from price column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a price column which is string and has price for the product from all over the world , now When I try to perform any operation like sum I am getting error.
So my question is how can I remove currency symbol from price column for all the countries?

Here is my sample input:-

```
locale   price 
cs_CZ   2462475,38 K
da_DK   kr 591.872,50
de_AT    267,70
de_CH   CHF 1'998.99
de_DE   1.798,09 
en_AE   AED7,236.20
en_AU   $1,699.00 
en_BD   Tk999,999.00
en_HK   HK$6,188.00
en_HU   Ft344,524,655.48
tr_TR   2.344.697,66 TL
```

Comment: Don't store those characters! Use constraints, correct data types, triggers etc, clean your data at insert/update! (Now you also have the issue decimal point or decimal comma...)

Comment: Historical data is already there in table so i can not clean.

Comment: Are you allowed to update table data? If it's less than millions of rows you can simply use REPLACE over and over again until all the different currency symbols and blanks are gone, then you have the decimal point/comma problem. If it's always two decimals, it's easy, otherwise maybe you can look at third character from the end and see if it's a digit or not etc.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have both decimal point and decimal comma but always two decimals (hopefully in the rest of the data too).

1. You can start by putting those values in a value list for testing (adding extra single quotes where needed).
2. Then you have to trim out spaces and letters with regular expressions.  In the inner SELECT you get the substring with single quotes and commas for thousand separators still in it.
3. In the outer SELECT you replace the decimal commas in the decimal side and strip out thousand separators on the integer side. The result is cast to type numeric with which you can count sums etc.

   ```
   SELECT (
       regexp_replace(left(substring, length(substring) -3),'[.,'']','','g')
           || replace(right(substring, 3),',','.'))::numeric,
       *
       FROM (
           SELECT substring(column1 from '(([0-9]+[,.''])*[0-9]+[.,][0-9]{2})[^0-9]*$'),
           column1
           FROM (
               VALUES ('2462475,38 K'),
                   ('kr 591.872,50'),
                   ('267,70'),
                   ('CHF 1''998.99'),
                   ('1.798,09'),
                   ('AED7,236.20'),
                   ('$1,699.00'),
                   ('Tk999,999.00'),
                   ('HK$6,188.00'),
                   ('Ft344,524,655.48'),
                   ('2.344.697,66 TL')
           ) currencies
       ) sq1;
   ```

The following is the whole answer compatible with 9.0 version of PostgreSQL (no left() or right() functions used). Also values list is replaced with a SELECT query that you can replace with your own table and column. Finally it's all been enclosed in a SELECT query that demonstrates the use of the sum-function.

```
SELECT sum(numeric) FROM (
    SELECT (
        regexp_replace(substr(substring, 0, length(substring) -3),'[.,'']','','g')
            || replace(substr(substring, length(substring) -3, length(substring)),',','.'))::numeric,
        *
        FROM (
            SELECT substring(column1 from '(([0-9]+[,.''])*[0-9]+[.,][0-9]{2})[^0-9]*$'),
                column1
                FROM (
                    SELECT column1 FROM your_table
                ) currencies
        ) sq1
    ) sq2
```

Comment: I tried running above query but its throwing error.

Comment: What is the error? If the PostgreSQL version is too old to recognize left- and right-functions you can for example replace left()-function with:
`substr(substring, 0, length(substring) -3)`
and right()-function with:
`substr(substring, length(substring) -3, length(substring))`

If it's something else, please describe the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres offloads most locale handling to the operating system. So the Postgres currency conversion routines will only work for you if the OS understands the locale names, and your price strings match its expected format.

For example, Windows won't accept `da_DK` as a locale, and even if it did, it will not accept the string `kr 591.872,50`, as it expects the Danish currency symbol to be `kr.` instead of `kr`.

That said, I think this should work reasonably well on a Linux-based server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert_currency(amount TEXT, locale TEXT) RETURNS NUMERIC AS
$$
BEGIN
  PERFORM set_config('lc_monetary', locale || '.UTF-8', True);
  RETURN amount::MONEY::NUMERIC;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
SET lc_monetary TO DEFAULT;
```